# How to pass incoming integer parameter value in json request while making a POST request

Tags: c#, json

Making a POST request for the API, passing incoming json body as hardcoded string. Fine with all hardcoded values, only need to pass **ID** based on incoming parameter **incomingID** (int)

Checked couple of articles/questions, but didn't any clear answer. Please suggest/guide how to replace this hardcoded value 123456 with incoming parameter value (incomingID)

[Replace field in Json file with some other value](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0e353e86-7d3d-4ae0-82e0-2e53dae46e62/replace-field-in-json-file-with-some-other-value?forum=csharpgeneral)

[How to replace placeholders inside json string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892440/how-to-replace-placeholders-inside-json-string)

```
private void CallAPI(int incomingID)
        {

            const string apiURL = "API URL"; // some test API
            string getInfoResult = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiURL);
                webrequest.Method = "POST";
                webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webrequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = "{\"Information\":{\"messageHeader\":{\"message\":\"getInfo\",\"transactionDate\":\"2021-05-11T12:05:54.000\", \"transactionID\":\"2021-05-15T12:05:54.000-12345\",\"payLoadFormat\":\"V1\",\"ID\":123456}}}"; //pass this incomingID based on parameter value

                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                }

                HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

                Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
                getInfoResult = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
                webresponse.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Will this simple concatenation: $"{{\"Information\":{{\"messageHeader\":{{\"message\":\"getInfo\",\"transactionDate\":\"2021-05-11T12:05:54.000\", \"transactionID\":\"2021-05-15T12:05:54.000-12345\",\"payLoadFormat\":\"V1\",\"ID\":{incomingID}}}}" work for you? Note that open figure brackets need to be escaped like "{{".

Comment: @RelativeLayouter no this I already tried, it gives as error - string is not json formatted

Comment: One moment, i will write answer properly - too much text for just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this, you can use simple interpolation:

```
string json = $"{{\"Information\":{{\"messageHeader\":{{\"message\":\"getInfo\",\"transactionDate\":\"2021-05-11T12:05:54.000\", \"transactionID\":\"2021-05-15T12:05:54.000-12345\",\"payLoadFormat\":\"V1\",\"ID\":{incomingID}}}}}}}"
```

Note that open and close brackets should be repeated twice to escape them. But, this is weird and not so common way to make JSON strings. Better use *serialization* to achieve your goal. For an example, use Newtonsoft.Json nuget to (de)serialize your objects. What you need to do:

1. Create your models as separate classes:

**PayloadFormat.cs**

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] // this string will force your enum serialize as "V1" instead of "0"
public enum PayloadFormat
{
    V1,
    V2,
    V3
}
```

**MessageHeader.cs**

```
public class MessageHeader
{
    public MessageHeader(string message, DateTime transactionDate, string transactionId, PayloadFormat payloadFormat, int id)
    {
        Message = message;
        TransactionDate = transactionDate;
        TransactionId = transactionId;
        PayloadFormat = payloadFormat;
        Id = id;
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; } // change type if you need to
    public string TransactionId { get; set; } // change type if you need to
    public PayloadFormat PayloadFormat { get; set; } // change type if you need to
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Information.cs**

```
public class Information
{
    public Information(MessageHeader messageHeader)
    {
        MessageHeader = messageHeader;
    }

    public MessageHeader MessageHeader { get; set; }
}
```

2. Create an instance of your `Information` class:

```
var information = new Information(new MessageHeader("getInfo", DateTime.Now, $"{DateTime.Now}-12345", PayloadFormat.V1, incomingID));
```

3. Serialize your string (make sure you are `using Newtonsoft.Json;`):

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(information);
```

Then use your json as you need to. The result will be:

```
{
    "MessageHeader": {
        "Message": "getInfo",
        "TransactionDate": "2022-05-17T19:45:33.2161326+05:00",
        "TransactionId": "17.05.2022 19:45:33-12345",
        "PayloadFormat": "V1",
        "Id": 5
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked 

string json = $"{{\"Information\":{{\"messageHeader\":{{\"message\":\"getInfo\",\"transactionDate\":\"2021-05-11T12:05:54.000\", \"transactionID\":\"2021-05-15T12:05:54.000-12345\",\"payLoadFormat\":\"V1\",\"ID\":{incomingID}}}}}}}"